# Multi-purpose 3d Artificial Life Engine?

Tags: open-source, physics, artificial-life

Studying emergence, it's quite useful to have a development framework to build upon to quickly test out new ideas. 3d with physics collision would be nice, and open-source would be a big plus. For this purpose 'breve' looks quite promising, but I was wondering if anyone had used it or knows of any other suitable engines?

Comment: Do you know [critterding](http://critterding.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 2):

For quick development, breve does look appropriate. If you want to write something more from scratch, [ODE](http://www.ode.org/), [Bullet](http://code.google.com/p/bullet/) and [Tokamak](http://www.tokamakphysics.com/) are all good open-source 3D physics and collision detection libraries.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question right, what you're looking for is more a programmable 3D graphics / physics engine sandbox to try out ideas, than anything specifically to do with artificial life.

If so, you might want to take a look at [fluxus](http://www.pawfal.org/fluxus/) - it's basically that, where the "programmable" part is Scheme.  It's designed for *interactive* programming (draw 3D scenes and animations, then change them in real time), so I'd guess it should be flexible enough for agent-based AI/AL.

Answer (score 1):

I would go ahead and use **breve**.  If you hadn't mentioned breve in your question, I would have recommended it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think that something like Microsoft Robotics Studio would be good for this.

Comment: Even though open-source would be a big plus?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not 100% what you are looking for, but you can try [Open steer](http://opensteer.sourceforge.net/) as a possible starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally code it up myself with Processing or ODE. It would be really fast, as there are numerous librairies out there available for both.

But I guess you can also use one of these (non-exhaustive list):

- Breve: http://spiderland.org/
- Jinngine: https://code.google.com/p/jinngine/

Answer (score -1):

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700567/open-source-pure-java-physics-dynamics-library) recently with respect to robotics simulation.

[JBullet](http://jbullet.advel.cz/) (a Java port of the Bullet Physics engine) came out as the top recommendation.

I'm using this in combination with [jMonkeyEngine](http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/) (which is a fully featured and popular game engine) for the rendering, camera control, scene graph management etc. This seems to be working very nicely so far as the two have been designed to work together.