# Open source, pure Java physics / dynamics library

Tags: java, open-source, simulation, physics, collision-detection

I'm looking for a lightweight, pure Java physics engine to do some simulations for robotic motion control.

My requirements:

- Rigid body physics
- Joint constraints and forces
- Convex object collision detection
- Lightweight, pure Java so it can be embedded in my application
- Ability to run simulations quickly
- Handles 50-100 objects comfortably
- Open source

Rather than reinventing the wheel, can you recommend any existing libraries that would fit the bill?

p.s. I have Googled already - I'm just keen to get honest opinions from people who have already used or implemented such things!

Comment: Its been a long time since I have used physics libraries so I haven't used the latest.  Doesn't JBullet do most of this?  http://jbullet.advel.cz/

Comment: Yeah it looks pretty good - probably the lead candidate right now unless someone has better ideas!

Comment: Now there is a software recommendations SE: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have used JBullet and JBox2D.  They both are good libraries.  JBox2D is more actively being changed, but JBullet has slightly larger base.

Just for fun, I was trying to simulate an old physics problem recently, for which I posted the results [here](http://standardwisdom.com/softwarejournal/2010/07/an-old-physics-problem/).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! Were there any big differences between JBullet and JBox2D in terms of approach, capabilities or performance?

Comment: Also it looks like JBox2D is 2D only... may rule it out for some of my applications

Comment: Hmmm, I just found JBox2D to be easier to work with - but that was probably simply because the exact problem I was working with was more aligned to one of JBox2D examples.  But yes, JBox2D is 2D only, and that may be a limiting factor.

Btw, I found the performance of JBox2D *very* good - using with a 100 objects etc.  A comparison of JBox2D with a different engine (Phys2D) can be found here: http://ciardhubh.de/node/15.  That article does mention https://jmephysics.dev.java.net/ as a 3D engine candidate, but I have not worked with it.

Answer (score 2):

I would also use JBullet, though its been a couple of years since I last worked with it.